# Intersection form and geometric cycles

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose you have a closed oriented smooth manifold $X$. And two orientable submanifolds $S_{1},S_{2}$ with $\dim(S_{1}) + \dim(S_{2}) = \dim(X)$ intersecting transversally and with $[S_{1}] \cdot [S_{2}] = 0$. Suppose that we are interested in finding a cycle $C \in C_{\dim(S_{1})}(X)$, such that $[C]=[S_{1}] \in H_{\dim(S_{1})}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $C$ is disjoint from $S_{2}$.

I have heard cautionary tale that it is not always possible to find such a cycle. On the other hand, I have a vague recollection of an argument in geometric topology when we "bring together" (probably by some kind of homotopy of $S_{1}$) the +1 and -1 intersection points and they annihilate each other or something like that, although that was probably in some specific situation or is perhaps not applicable here.

I would be interested to know a counter-example, or some reference that addresses this in a reasonably general way. I wonder if this is a phenomina "linearises" in the sense algebraic topology for high dimensions i.e. is it possible to find such a $C$ if we assume that $\dim(X)>>0$ or $\dim(X)>> \dim(S_{1})$?

Comment: If the $S_i$ are connected and the manifold $X$ is simply connected of dim $\geq 5$, the argument you have in mind is the Whitney trick: connect two intersection points of opposite sign by a path in $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively, and then fill the union of those paths in with a disc; isotope the arc in $S_1$ across this disc until you can finally push it off of $S_2$. This is the so-called Whitney trick.

Comment: for curves on a surface this is very much impossible, though.

Comment: @ Mike Miller, thanks! could you sketch counter example?

Comment: I parsed your original question as asking for *isotopies* of $S_i$ as opposed to simply homologous cycles (through no fault of your own). The latter seems 
more plausible. I think it is true for oriented surfaces "by hand".

Comment: [This question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/77003/40804) seems to answer your question in the affirmative.